# Getting Form Element in event handler

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add an `onSubmit` event to ALL of the `HTML Forms` to validate submitting  File Size and prevent its submission via `javascript`.

the problem is that I do not have the `id` of the `form`, neither those of the `file input element`. Now, How can I access to the value of the desired `input`?

It may be several `forms` in each page with unknown `id`'s but each `form` has just one `file input element`. The `id` of the element is also unknown.

example `form`:

```
<form onSubmit="checkSize(1000000)" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="changedata.php" method="post" >
      <input class="user_upload_file" type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

and the javascript I use:

```
function checkSize(max_img_size)
{

    //file_input_id is unknown so, the following input could not be defines:
    var input = document.getElementById("file_input_id");
    // check for browser support (may need to be modified)
    if(input.files && input.files.length == 1)
    {           
        if (input.files[0].size > max_img_size) 
        {
            alert("File size is too big. ");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, it is not possible for me to change the `id` of all the `file input`s, It's really time consuming. I also DO NOT use `jQuery`.

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers included via intrinsic event attributes are called in the context of the element to which they are attached, you can pass that around like any other variable.

```
onsubmit="checkSize(1000000, this)"
```

From there you can use standard DOM methods like `getElementsByTagName` and `querySelector` along with the `elements` property to find descendent elements.

Comment: Thank you very much Quentin, Your answer helped me so much.